# Colon use inside function declaration

Tags: c#

I saw a code, where a colon was used inside a function declaration:

DoWork(Param1:Param2)

I know that a colon is for inheritance: `class Child: Parent` 
But, what is the purpose of the colon when it used before variable?

**EDIT I've corrected the question**

Comment: Are you sure they are not inside caller code instead of declaration code?

Comment: I believe it was caller code. Otherwise such declaration would not compile

Comment: @LordTitiKaka In other words, are you sure that the line you saw contained `public void` as well as `:`? Because this line as it is appears to be syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy you correct , I've edited the question , Now +1 me please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Named optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Its so you can have an optional number of arguments supplied, but the compiler needs to know which arguments to marry up to which parameters, otherwise defaults will be used for the others.

Answer (score 0):

And now the question that looms in the minds of many, and ardent C# admirers knit their brows in perplexity: why do we have to use ':' for named parameters? Surely the "=" would be much better?

Well, the reason for using colons instead of equals is simple: the equal sign already has a meaning.

```
int myInt;

CallMe(myInt = 5);  //set myInt variable to 5

CallMe(myInt : 5);  //set myInt parameter of CallMe method to 5
```

Comment: Thats when you call the method, not when you declare the method.

Comment: True in your example, but the question is about the use of a colon in the declaration of a method.